# Samsung Smart TV get name of logged user

Tags: javascript, html, dom, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

How can I get name of current logged user in SmartHub? I have settings.xml file, in which are saved settings for application, but i need to create different xml for every user, so i need get user name or some ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think possibly Stack Overflow isn't the right place for this question, especially as it is very localized to the Samsung SmartTV SDK, but the thing you are looking for is SERVICE_USERNAME I believe (look at this post: 
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tec00157/index.html)

You should probably post on the Samsung forum: http://www.samsungdforum.com/

Comment: thanks for advice but I didn't found answer on the Samsung forum and noticed that there are lots of unanswered but relevant questions...

Comment: @Ka-EM Okay well I'd just wait for someone who's "in the know" to come along and help out!

Comment: Your link is irrelevant: it describe Basic Authentification for XMLHttpRequest, SERVICE_USERNAME is just example variable for code block.

Answer (score 0):

Smart Hub UserId is passed in query string for launched application index.html file, you can find details in [article about Single Sing-On](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00053/index.html)